# USB wireless card Atheros AR9271 not working in VirtualBox

Tags: wireless, usb, virtualbox, atheros

i cannot get my card (TP-Link TL-WN722N) to work on BackTrack 5 r1 (kernel 2.6.39.4), installed on VirtualBox

```
#lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

# iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

I have installed `compat-wireless-2012-02-06` and selected `ath9k_htc` drivers.

Any clues?

I can post anything else you need.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having trouble with this as well.

Comment: I switched to VMWare and it worked... Hope it helps

Comment: Back track questions are off topic.